# Make { ( and ) } normal mode motions skip blank lines

Tags: vimscript, key-bindings, object-motions

Normal mode `)` `}` and `(` `{` navigate paragraphs and lines but they don't skip blank lines. (They land on them.)

This is obviously the preferable behavior when writing code, but when writing "normal" text it's infuriating. I would like to jump to the beginning of the next sentence/paragraph respectively, not the empty lines I leave between them for readability while editing the text.

Perhaps a solution would be: detecting current position after the initial movement, and while current position = white-space, do a `w` normal motion. Regrettably, I don't know how to string these commands in a `vim.keymap.set`, even if it is the right way to go about this.

This is all in Neovim. (Hence the `vim.keymap.set`) That being said, both the original behavior and the answer should be vim/neovim agnostic (now and in the future,) and hopefully serve both.

**A more detailed explanation:**

*With the cursor at amet, a `}` or a `)` followed by another `)` will land me at the blank line between consequat and Duis. Desired behavior is to land on Duis. Similar behavior for `{` and `(` if starting from Ut Excepteur. Desired behavior is for it also to skip (n) number of blank lines: if there were three or ten blank lines between the paragraphs they should be skipped just the same as one blank line.*

*To explain the purpose of this, I add blank lines for readability while editing, but it messes with the navigation of the text since neovim interprets blanks lines as "Oh, you are probably writing code and those blank lines are important landmarks for you, let me land you there.*

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
> eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
> minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
> aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
>
> Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum
> dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
> proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est
> laborum.

Example text for Vivian (for context, go through the comments.) :

```
 <Empty first line>
 (1)This is a line without quotes.

(2)”This is a line with quotes,” she said. (3)”This is a line with quotes.”
”This is a line with quotes,” he said.
”This is a line with quotes.”
”This is another line with quotes.”
”This is a line with quotes.” This is a line without quotes. (4)”This is a line with quotes."

This is a line without quotes.<EOF>
```

Legend: Numbers in parenthesis and <> are not part of the text. I've inserted them to simplify explaining motions.
When descending, it jumps from 1 to 2 to 3, then all the way to 4.
When ascending, It goes 4 3 2 1. In neither case does it acknowledge the final line.

Comment: Vim script works just fine with vim.cmd[[..]] you are indeed correct. My reasoning for mentioning neovim is that something might work differently (either now or in the future) in neovim compared to vim and potentially confuse anyone looking at this question.

Comment: There was a time (not that long ago) when vimscript was utterly confusing to me. I hope the edit above helps steer people in the right direction. @Rich

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @romaini my fiddling with if ... then and nextword (w) was so stupid I wouldn't dare post it anywhere. Vivian 's answer provides the functionality I am looking for and seems way more elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
function! NextParagraph()
  if getbufline('%', line('.')) == ['']
    call search('\v(%^|\S)', 'b')
  endif
  call search('\v(%^\n?|\n\n)\s*\zs\S')
endfunction

nnoremap } <Cmd>call NextParagraph()<CR>

function! PreviousParagraph()
  call search('\v(%^\n?|\n\n)\s*\zs\S', 'b')
endfunction

nnoremap { <Cmd>call PreviousParagraph()<CR>

function! NextSentence()
  if getbufline('%', line('.')) == ['']
    call search('\v(%^|\S)', 'b')
  endif
  call search('\v(%^\n?|\n\n|[.?!](\_\s|["“”]))\_\s*\zs\S')
endfunction

nnoremap ) <Cmd>call NextSentence()<CR>

function! PreviousSentence()
  call search('\v(%^\n?|\n\n|[.?!](\_\s|["“”]))\_\s*\zs\S', 'b')
endfunction

nnoremap ( <Cmd>call PreviousSentence()<CR>
```

The start of a paragraph are defined as a non blank (`\S`) text following:

- A blank line (`\n\n`)
- The beginning of the buffer (`\%^\n\?`)

The sentences are defined as a non blank (`\S`) text following:

- A blank line (`\n\n`)
- The beginning of the buffer (`\%^\n\?`)
- A sentence punctuation (`.`, `?`, `!`) followed by a space  , a tab, a new line or a quote `"` (`(\_\s|")`).

The `\zs` makes that the cursor goes right before the non blank text and not at the start of the pattern.

The call to `search()` avoid that the `/` search register is modified.

Comment: Hello @Vivian, thanks for your answer! It definetely is in the right direction, but several behaviors are off. When hitting ) it skips the first sentence after and empty line if the last sentence ended in ". ) also highlights everything. (because of the search.) { and } skip the blank line correctly but never land  on the first word of the next paragraph. It is movement more akin to j and k if j and k moved by paragraph blocks.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm not sure I grab correctly the weakness of the proposed solution. It would be good if you could give some more example of what is desired. Would that be possible?

Comment: This would be greatly improved by explanation

Comment: I'll do as soon as the OP validates the solution ;-)

Comment: I will add them to the main body of the question for clarity (so that anyone else that comes across this can understand with a cursory glance.) I should also say, I did not yet try the edited version of your answer, only the first one that was 3 lines long. What you have now posted might be the answer, I will try immediately after I edit my original question above.

Comment: @Vivian your solution works perfectly, I just it tested on a very long Lorem Ipsum with a varying number of blank lines between paragraphs. It behaves precisly as desired, thank you. One final question, is there a reason you haven't added the ( ? Is it harder to achieve with the above code?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I suppose the ( should not be hard to add. I didn't wrote it because it was not mentioned in your question but I could propose you a version ;-)

Comment: @ Vivian you are correct, and I just noticed it wasn't included in the original question. Lax proofreading once more rears its ugly head. Thank you again, I would greatly appreciate it if you could add it to your answer. I will edit the question accordingly.

Comment: For anyone that may stumble on this in the future: Although originally I thought it did, the `(` and `)` become really erratic when they encounter `"` at the beginning or end of a sentence. (Lorem Ipsum turns out was a poor test for that.) `{` and `}` work absolutely as intend though and since I found out I don't really need the `)` and `(` functionality when `{` and `}` work so well, I will not pester anyone for functionality I don't need. Still, be warned `(` and `)` don't work when sentences start or end with `"` (dialogue.)

Comment: @Anthony, I have tried to make the solution working better with quotes and to make new sentence closer to what they are in Vim.

Comment: @ Vivian first off, let me start again by thanking you. And by saying the paragraph movement proved sufficient for me. Regarding the sentence movement, it is still erratic. Less so, compared to the previous iteration, but erratic. When it comes upon: "Placeholder 1." Placeholder 2. "Placeholder 3." It will jump from 1 to 3, or 3 to 1 if you are going the other direction. It will also Jump blocks of "a whole sentence is here," if they are one after the other with no blank lines between them, just like if I was using `}` ot `{`.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I'll have a look this weekend ;-)

Comment: I have tried to reproduce your problem but without success. Maybe be I don't have the correct text. Could you add it to your question such that I know where are the new line placed.

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt I added the example. Thank *you* for taking the time to help.

Comment: Thanks for your patience @Antony. I have adapted the solution. The solution assume quotation using the standard quote `"` like the standard Vim sentences. I notice that in your example you are using another quote (`”`) I could also adapt the solution for that if needed.

Comment: Might be my font. (It's a non standard typewriter font.) I hadn't noticed that. No need to adapt it, I can do it myself now that you pointed me to the crux of the issue. Edit: I see that you already did, thank you! :)